# Can any one solve this Linq error -?

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote the query like this

```
 var gradeValue = from DataRow gradeRow in GraceTable.Rows
                             let marksAbove = gradeRow.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_ABOVE") 
                             let marksBelow = gradeRow.Field<decimal>("EXG_MARKS_BELOW")
                             where obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") >= marksAbove && obtMarksRow.Field<decimal>("Percentage") <= marksBelow
                             select gradeRow.Field<string>("EXG_GRADE_NAME");
```

but i am getting the value `(gradeValue.ToString() )` as

```
"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Data.DataRow,System.String]"
```

Whats wrong ?

i tried  `select gradeRow["EXG_GRADE_NAME"].ToString() & gradeRow.Field<string>("EXG_GRADE_NAME").First() ;` also. But Still i get same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `gradeValue` is an enumeration which is a collection of values.  It appears that you expect it to be a single value or want the display for the first item in the collection.  If so then do the following

```
gradeValue.First().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

make that var gradeValue as         List         gradeValue